# how to return a Mongoose nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I am trying to return a nested Object that I declared in my mongoose model as follows:

```
const MessageSchema = new Schema({
    messageLog: [
        {
        transcript: {
            type: String
        },
        recipient: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true
        },
        sender: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User',
            required: true
        }
    }]
});
```

however I am not able to get the value for the inner object back when I try to query for it via a graphql resolver (transcript, sender, recipient are null on gql playground, but updated in db) I have set it up as follows:

```
query = args.messageId ? { _id: args.messageId } : { _id: new ObjectId() };

const message = await Message.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$addToSet: {messageLog: {transcript: args.messageBody, sender: args.senderId, recipient: args.recipientId}}}, {$setOnInsert: args, upsert: true, new: true, runValidators: true})
return message.messageLog;
```

I am able to create the new object and the nested messageLog in the db but I can only return the id for some reason as opposed to the the messageLog array of objects. Usually the issue lies in how I am resolving (resolvers) but I am going to put my typeDef here as well in case the issue lies there.

```
type Message {
        _id: ID
        transcript: [String]
        recipient: [User]
        sender: [User]
    }
```

Comment: What strikes me as odd is that your mongoose schema defines a log as an array of message, but your GraphQL schema instead defines each method property as an array. Maybe this is your issue?

Comment: @Herku the mongoose schema is an array of objects but the graphql schema is returning me the array of those values since they are not themselves defined types/schemas. Thats how I am thinking of it, and it might not be allowed that way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution in case anyone has a similar schema setup and issue is to reference the the typeDefs with the nested levels as well. So since transcript, recipient and sender were nested a level down, the typeDef would have to be defined for the nested object and then referenced on the message type as follows:

```
type messageLog {
        _id: ID
        transcript: String
        recipient: User
        sender: User
    }
    type Message {
        _id: ID
        messageLog: [messageLog]
    }
```

and to use populate for the User since it was a schema referenced by the objectId